# How to configure Apache to use ipaddress/~username

Tags: apache, webserver

I need to test a website before switching its DNS and I'd like to learn how to configure the webserver in order to access sites with http://ipaddress/~username, like cPanel does.
I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mod_userdir provides the ~username support.  On ubuntu, use a2enable userdir to load and configure mod_userdir.  By default, your server should respond to requests to its own IP address so no action is required there.